# Why I might suddenly get persmission denied when I just open TortoiseHG?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, tortoisehg

I installed TortoiseHG 5.6.1 (x64) on guest Win 7 Ultimate x64 in VirtualBox. The host OS is Win10 Enterprise x64. When I right-click in any folder and select "Hg Workbench", it opens successfully. After that, I accidentelly deleted the *.vdi file and had to reinstall both OS and TortoiseHG again. But, this time when I right-click and select "Hg Workbench" I always get this error:

[image]

I tried older TortoiseHG versions, but I get the same error. I even tried to reinstall guest OS again, but it didn't help. I just installed OS and TortoiseHG, so what can be that I did accidentally the first time and/or other times?

**UPDATE 1**

I installed TortoiseHG 5.6.1 (x64) on guest Win 10 x64 in VirtualBox and I didn't get that error message. So, it has to be something with Win 7. What can that be?